# Import part of tree with subclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse

We have a huge, old, and ugly SVN repo, with a `main` folder on the top.
This folder contains the `branches` folder (with the core of our code), as well as several other folders `F1`, `F2`, `F3`... that contain some dependencies.

I would like to import in a **single** Eclipse project, by using subclipse, a particular branch as well as only folders `F1` and `F3`. But subclipse doesn't seem to allow a checkout in an existing Eclipse project (but perhaps is my intent totally stupid?). And what if I want to import folders that are outside `main`?

Answer (score 0):

An Eclipse project that is linked with Subclipse has to be a single SVN working copy rooted at the top folder of the Eclipse project.  So any legitimate way that exists to construct a valid working copy would work.  This could be checking out the top level folder using the Depth = Immediates option and then using the update set-depth option to expand specific folders.  You could use Switch to swap out some folders with those from a different branch.  You can use svn:externals to pull in folders from other locations etc.

It is hard to say which, if any, of these options might work for you.